# Calling class from regular expression in codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want to call any class by regular expression in codeigniter 4 (routes). In version 3, I used the following command:

```
$route['^(.*?)-([A-Za-z]+)(\.([A-Za-z0-9_]+))*(\.php)+$'] = '$2/$4';
```

But for version 4, I need to use following code:

```
$routes->add('^(.*?)-([A-Za-z]+)(\.([A-Za-z0-9_]+))*(\.php)+$', '$2::$4');
```

The output is

> Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers$2::Edit

For example URL: *http://localhost/Codeigniter-4.0.4/News-Admin.Edit.php*
I want the Admin class with Edit function (Admin::Edit ) be called.
How can I call any class defined by regular expression?

Comment: Please add example URL which matches with pattern in CI3

Comment: Please look for my regex test (your pattern fully matches the sample text): https://regexr.com/5jaj5

Comment: @AdamP. I added the URL. My problem is not about regular expression. My problem is about calling the class specified by the regex pattern.

Comment: In CI route rules the segments separated by forward slash (/): eg: example.com/controller/menthod/1st-param/2nd-param/nth-param... 
e.g: `$routes->add('products/([a-z]+)/(\d+)', 'Products::show/$1/id_$2');`

Comment: Thanks @AdamP. , I need Products:: calss be retrieved from regex. In this case, it is predefined.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not an existing project I recommed for you to create an **Admin** subdirectory **in Contorollers** directory, then create here the **News** controller and add to it the **edit** method/function which matches to following route rule:
`$routes->add('admin/news/edit');` This is easier than override CI routing logic